# Multer returning undefined for svg image file upload

Tags: node.js, reactjs, svg, multer

I want to upload svg image to my NodeJs - Express server from React ( using Redux ). I am using signature_pad npm module for drawing signatures.
This is code in React:

```
        formData.append('contractId', contractId);
        formData.append('svg_signature',signaturePad.toDataURL("image/svg+xml"));

        dispatch(sign_contract_action(formData));
```

This is what **signaturePad.toDataURL("image/svg+xml")** looks like:

```
 data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDov...
```

This is my express router:

```
router.post('/sign-contract',upload_file.single('svg_signature'),save_svg_signature);
```

And this is the part where I want to receive svg image file and store it but it is undefined:

```
const save_svg_signature = async (req,res,next) => {
    const { file } = req;
    const { contractId } = req.body;
    console.log(contractId); // works
    console.log(file); // undefined
};
```